# Python выдает ошибку при подключении модуля

Tags: python, модули

Я пишу допустим import (модуль), который я заранее установил в pip, но при запуске моего кода, пишет что модуль не надйен. Как это исправить?

Comment: Может быть у вас два python'а установлено? py -V вроде бы.

Comment: Чтобы это исправить, сначала нужно задать нормальный вопрос - приведите версию python, сколько вообще версий у вас установлено, есть ли виртуальное окружение, какой модуль...

Comment: Python 3.8.1 - версия, модуль - telebot, версии вроде 2, вроде 1, вроде бы 2.7 удалял

Comment: 3 версии оказалось, так что 2 удалил, но все равно ошибка. Что деелать?

Comment: @TheNick-Ник посмотрите подробнее сообщение об ошибке (бывает, что сам модуль импортируется успешно, но при этом тянет за собой зависимости, которых может не быть на диске).